# Can't prevent CheckBoxList control from overflowing

Tags: asp.net, css, web-controls

`<div>` element with fixed width contains CheckboxList control. Since ListItems can be added by users to this control, there’s a possibility that particular ListItem could overflow parent `<div>` due to having too large text. I’ve tried preventing this by setting overflow property:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkAllRoles" style="overflow:hidden;" ... />
```

but to no effect. Is there some other way to prevent ListItem from overflowing?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Did you try "`overflow: hidden`" on the parent div? That's what would control the overflowing of the parent container.

Setting overflow on the list items will be hard to control, as they are rendered as `<td>` cells.